# Does arm-none-eabi-gcc produce slower code than Keil uVision

Tags: c, gcc, arm, stm32

I have a simple blinking led program running on STM32f103C8 (without initialization boilerplate):

```
void soft_delay(void) {
    for (volatile uint32_t i=0; i<2000000; ++i) { }
}

  uint32_t iters = 0;
  while (1)
  {
    LL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin);
    soft_delay();
    ++iters;
  }
```

It was compiled with both `Keil uVision v.5` (default compiler) and `CLion` using `arm-none-eabi-gcc` compiler.
The surprise is that arm-none-eabi-gcc program runs 50% slower in Release mode (-O2 -flto) and 100% slower in Debug mode.

I suspect 3 reasons:

- Keil over-optimization (unlikely, because the code is very simple)
- arm-none-eabi-gcc under-optimization due to wrong compiler flags (I use CLion Embedded plugins` CMakeLists.txt)
- A bug in the initialization so that chip has lower clock frequency with arm-none-eabi-gcc (to be investigated)

I have not yet dived into the jungles of optimization and disassembling, 
I hope that there are many experienced embedded developers who already encountered this issue and have the answer.

**UPDATE 1**

Playing around with different optimization levels of Keil ArmCC, I see
how it affects the generated code. And it affects drastically, especially execution time. Here are the benchmarks and disassembly of `soft_delay()` function for each optimization level (RAM and Flash amounts include initialization code).

-O0: RAM: 1032, Flash: 1444, Execution Time (20 iterations): 18.7 sec

```
soft_delay PROC
        PUSH     {r3,lr}
        MOVS     r0,#0
        STR      r0,[sp,#0]
        B        |L6.14|
|L6.8|
        LDR      r0,[sp,#0]
        ADDS     r0,r0,#1
        STR      r0,[sp,#0]
|L6.14|
        LDR      r1,|L6.24|
        LDR      r0,[sp,#0]
        CMP      r0,r1
        BCC      |L6.8|
        POP      {r3,pc}
        ENDP
```

-O1: RAM: 1032, Flash: 1216, Execution Time (20 iterations): 13.3 sec

```
soft_delay PROC
        PUSH     {r3,lr}
        MOVS     r0,#0
        STR      r0,[sp,#0]
        LDR      r0,|L6.24|
        B        |L6.16|
|L6.10|
        LDR      r1,[sp,#0]
        ADDS     r1,r1,#1
        STR      r1,[sp,#0]
|L6.16|
        LDR      r1,[sp,#0]
        CMP      r1,r0
        BCC      |L6.10|
        POP      {r3,pc}
        ENDP
```

-O2 -Otime: RAM: 1032, Flash: 1136, Execution Time (20 iterations): 9.8 sec

```
soft_delay PROC
        SUB      sp,sp,#4
        MOVS     r0,#0
        STR      r0,[sp,#0]
        LDR      r0,|L4.24|
|L4.8|
        LDR      r1,[sp,#0]
        ADDS     r1,r1,#1
        STR      r1,[sp,#0]
        CMP      r1,r0
        BCC      |L4.8|
        ADD      sp,sp,#4
        BX       lr
        ENDP
```

-O3: RAM: 1032, Flash: 1176, Execution Time (20 iterations): 9.9 sec

```
soft_delay PROC
        PUSH     {r3,lr}
        MOVS     r0,#0
        STR      r0,[sp,#0]
        LDR      r0,|L5.20|
|L5.8|
        LDR      r1,[sp,#0]
        ADDS     r1,r1,#1
        STR      r1,[sp,#0]
        CMP      r1,r0
        BCC      |L5.8|
        POP      {r3,pc}
        ENDP
```

TODO: benchmarking and disassembly for `arm-none-eabi-gcc`.

Comment: You do not know what is going on in your code - but you try to compare performance. It is pointless. Generate the assembly file and see what is going on. But in this case there no too much to optimize for the both. Do no use magic functions as well.

Comment: @P__J__ You are right, but performance matters and I believe that I am not the first one who encountered this problem. And if there is no simple answer, I will then try the hard way.

Comment: BTW trust me (I do program ARM uCs as a daytime job) there is almost no difference between the modern compilers. The code is practically the same. IMO you waste your time. If performance is a problem - it is always programmer fault. Compilers will not turn bad code into a good code, and it does not matter how much you pay for the compiler.

Comment: Never blame the compiler - always blame yourself.

Comment: @P__J__ But don't you find this case interesting? Loosing 50% performance is not a mere trifle, is it?

Comment: No it is not interesting at all - example is extremely bad. Who cares about the performance of the program which consists only from the dead loop?. It is completely not interesting. And you do not even know what clock you are running.

Comment: @P__J__ give me a bit to post my examples and you will see how extremely relevant tiny programs are to demonstrating performance and performance differences.  they are in fact the easiest way to see/exploit performance issues.

Comment: Also there isn't a 'default' compiler with Keil. It could be the ARMcc 5/6 and ARM compiler 5/6. So 'default' is meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many factors at play here.  Certainly if you have an optimizing compiler and you compare optimized vs not DEPENDING ON THE CODE you can see a large difference in execution speed.  Using the volatile in the tiny loop here actually masks some of that, in both cases it should be read/written to memory every loop.

But the calling code the loop variable unoptimized would touch ram two or three times in that loop, optimized ideally would be in a register the whole time, making for a dramatic difference in execution performance even with zero wait state ram.

The toggle pin code is relatively large (talking to the peripheral directly would be less code), depending on whether that library was compiled separately with different options or at the same time with the same options makes a big difference with respect to performance.

Add that this is an mcu and running off of a flash which with the age of this part the flash might at best be half the clock rate of the cpu and worst a number of wait states and I don't remember off hand if ST had the caching in front of it at that time.  so every instruction you add can add a clock, so just the loop variable alone can dramatically change the timing.

Being a high performance pipelined core I have demonstrated here and elsewhere that alignment can (not always) play a role, so if in one case the exact same machine code links to address 0x100 in one case and 0x102 in another it is possible that exact same machine code takes extra or fewer clocks to execute based on the nature of the pre-fetcher in the design, or the flash implementation, cache if any implementation, branch predictor, etc.

And then the biggest problem is how did you time this, it is not uncommon for there to be error in not using a clock correctly such that the clock/timing code itself varies and is creating some of the difference.  Plus are there background things going on, interrupts/multitasking.

Michal Abrash wrote a wonderful book called The Zen of Assembly Language, you can get it for free in ePub or perhaps pdf form on GitHub.  the 8088 was obsolete when the book was released but if you focus on that then you have missed the point, I bought it when it came out and have used what I learned on nearly a daily basis.

gcc is not a high performance compiler it is more of a general purpose compiler built Unix style where you can have different language front ends and different target backends.  When I was in the position you are now trying to first understand these things I sampled many compilers for the same arm target and same C code and the results were vast.  Later I wrote an instruction set simulator so I could count instructions and memory accesses to compare gnu vs llvm, as the latter has more optimization opportunities than gnu but for execution tests of code gcc was faster sometimes but not slower.  That ended up being more of a long weekend having fun than something I used to analyze the differences.

It is easier to start with small-ish code like this and disassemble the two.  Understand that fewer instructions doesn't mean faster, one distant memory access on a dram based system can take hundreds of clock cycles, that might be replaced with another solution that takes a handful/dozen of linearly fetched instructions to end up with the same result (do some math vs look up something in a rarely sampled table) and depending on the situation the dozen instructions execute much faster.  at the same time the table solution can be much faster.  it depends.

Examination of the disassembly often leads to incorrect conclusions (read abrash, not just that book, everything) as first off folks think less instructions means faster code.  rearranging instructions in a pipelined processor can improve performance if you move an instruction into a time period that would have otherwise been wasted clocks.  incrementing a register not related to a memory access in front of the memory access instead of after in a non-superscaler processor.

Ahh, back to a comment.  This was years ago and competing compilers were more of a thing most folks just wrap their gui around gnu and the ide/gui is the product not the compiler.  But there was the arm compiler itself, before the rvct tools, ads and I forget the other, those were "better" than gcc.  I forget the names of the others but there was one that produced significantly faster code, granted this was Dhrystone so you will also find that they may tune optimizers for Dhrystone just to play benchmark games.  Now that I can see how easy it is to manipulate benchmarks I consider them to in general be bu33zzit, can't be trusted.  Kiel used to be a multi-target tool for mcus and similar, but then was purchased by arm and I thought at the time they were dropping all other targets, but have not checked in a while.  I might have tried them once to get access to a free/demo version of rvct as when I was working at one job we had a budget to buy multi-thousand dollar tools, but that didn't include rvct (although I was on phone calls with the formerly Allant folks who were part of a purchase that became the rvct tools) which I was eager to try once they had finished the development/integration of that product, by then didn't have a budget for that and later couldn't afford or wasn't interested in buying even kiels tools, much less arms.  Their early demos of rvct created an encrypted/obfuscated binary that was not arm machine code it only ran on their simulator so you couldn't use it to eval performance or to compare it to others, don't think they were willing to give us an un-obfuscated version and we weren't willing to reverse engineer it.  now it is easier just to use gcc or clang and hand optimize where NEEDED.  Likewise with experience can write C code that optimizes better based on experience examining compiler output.

You have to know the hardware, particularly in this case where you take processor IP and most of the chip is not related to the processor IP and most of the performance is not related to the processor IP (pretty much true for a lot of platforms today in particular your server/desktop/laptop).  The Gameboy Advance for example used a lot of 16 bit buses instead of 32, thumb tools were barely being integrated, but thumb mode while counting instructions/or bytes was like 10% more code at the time, executed significantly faster on that chip.  On other implementations both arm architecture and chip design thumb may have performance penalties, or not.

ST in general with the cortex-m products tends to put a cache in front of the flash, sometimes they document it and provide enable/disable control sometimes not so it can be difficult at best to get a real performance value as the typical thing is to run the code under test many times in a loop so you can get a better time measurement.  other vendors don't necessarily do this and it is much easier to see the flash wait states and get a real, worst case, timing value that you can use to validate your design.  caches in general as well as pipelines make it difficult at best to get good, repeatable, reliable numbers to validate your design.  So for example you sometimes cannot do the alignment trick to mess with performance of the same machine code on an st but on say a ti with the same core you can.  st might not give you the icache in a cortex-m7 where another vendor might since st has already covered that.  Even within one brand name though don't expect the results of one chip/family to translate to another chip/family even if they use the same core.  Also look at subtle comments in the arm documentation as to whether some cores offer a fetch size as an advertised option, single or multi-cycle multiply, etc.  and I'll tell you that there are other compile time options for the core that are not shown in the technical reference manual that can affect performance so don't assume that all cortex-m3s are the same even if they are the same revision from arm. The chip vendor has the source so they can go even further and modify it, or for example a register bank to be implemented by the consumer they might change it from no protection to parity to ecc which might affect performance while retaining all of arms original code as is.  When you look at an avr or pic though or even an msp430, while I cant prove it those designs appear more static not tiny vs Xmega vs regular old avr as there are definite differences there, but one tiny to another.

Your assumptions are a good start, there really isn't such a thing as over-optimization, more of a thing of missed optimizations, but there may be other factors you are not seeing in your assumptions that may or may not be see in a disassembly.  there are obvious things that we would expect like one of the loop variables to be register based vs memory based.  alignment, I wouldn't expect the clock settings to change if you used the same code, but a different set of experiments using timers or a scope you can measure the clock settings to see if they were configured the same.  background tasks, interrupts and dumb luck as to how/when they hit the test.  But bottom line, sometimes it is as simple as a missed optimization or subtle differences in how one compiler generates code to another, it is as often not those things and more of a system issue, memory speed, peripheral speed, caches or their architecture, how the various busses in the design operate, etc.  For some of these cortex-ms (and many other processors) you can exploit their bus behavior to show a performance difference in something that the average person wouldn't expect to see.

Comment: really short answer, if arm turned kiel into an arm tuned compiler, compared to gcc yes I would expect for decent sized projects kiel to produce faster code.  this isnt a decent sized experiment though.

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic answer. It is really helpful, but the problem deserves further investigation. Most interesting thing is that the code is very simple and the difference is big. I'm interested if anybody can reproduce my results and later I will publish the project on github to make that easier. Also I will measure MCU clock to eliminate initialization bugs.

Comment: please add more code to the question, including the disassembly showing relevant differences between kiel and gcc .

Comment: OK but that may take a day or two because I have plans for tomorrow)

Comment: Please, if you do the demonstration, post the link here

Answer (score 5):

This second answer is a demonstration of the kinds of things that would affect the performance results the OP may be seeing and examples of to possibly test for those STM32F103C8 blue pill.

Complete source code:

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

flash.s

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang
.thumb_func
hang:   b .

.align

.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
```

test.s

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.word 0,0,0
.word 0,0,0,0

.thumb_func
.globl TEST
TEST:
    bx lr
```

notmain.c

```
//PA9  TX
//PA10 RX

void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
void dummy ( unsigned int );

#define USART1_BASE 0x40013800
#define USART1_SR   (USART1_BASE+0x00)
#define USART1_DR   (USART1_BASE+0x04)
#define USART1_BRR  (USART1_BASE+0x08)
#define USART1_CR1  (USART1_BASE+0x0C)
#define USART1_CR2  (USART1_BASE+0x10)
#define USART1_CR3  (USART1_BASE+0x14)
//#define USART1_GTPR (USART1_BASE+0x18)
#define GPIOA_BASE  0x40010800
#define GPIOA_CRH   (GPIOA_BASE+0x04)
#define RCC_BASE    0x40021000
#define RCC_APB2ENR (RCC_BASE+0x18)

#define STK_CSR     0xE000E010
#define STK_RVR     0xE000E014
#define STK_CVR     0xE000E018
#define STK_MASK    0x00FFFFFF

static void uart_init ( void )
{
    //assuming 8MHz clock, 115200 8N1
    unsigned int ra;

    ra=GET32(RCC_APB2ENR);
    ra|=1<<2;   //GPIOA
    ra|=1<<14;  //USART1
    PUT32(RCC_APB2ENR,ra);

    //pa9 TX  alternate function output push-pull
    //pa10 RX configure as input floating
    ra=GET32(GPIOA_CRH);
    ra&=~(0xFF0);
    ra|=0x490;
    PUT32(GPIOA_CRH,ra);

    PUT32(USART1_CR1,0x2000);
    PUT32(USART1_CR2,0x0000);
    PUT32(USART1_CR3,0x0000);
    //8000000/16 = 500000
    //500000/115200 = 4.34
    //4 and 5/16 = 4.3125
    //4.3125 * 16 * 115200 = 7948800
    PUT32(USART1_BRR,0x0045);
    PUT32(USART1_CR1,0x200C);
}
static void uart_putc ( unsigned int c )
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(GET32(USART1_SR)&0x80) break;
    }
    PUT32(USART1_DR,c);
}
static void hexstrings ( unsigned int d )
{
    //unsigned int ra;
    unsigned int rb;
    unsigned int rc;

    rb=32;
    while(1)
    {
        rb-=4;
        rc=(d>>rb)&0xF;
        if(rc>9) rc+=0x37; else rc+=0x30;
        uart_putc(rc);
        if(rb==0) break;
    }
    uart_putc(0x20);
}
static void hexstring ( unsigned int d )
{
    hexstrings(d);
    uart_putc(0x0D);
    uart_putc(0x0A);
}

void soft_delay(void) {
    for (volatile unsigned int i=0; i<2000000; ++i) { }
}

int notmain ( void )
{

    PUT32(STK_CSR,4);
    PUT32(STK_RVR,0x00FFFFFF);
    PUT32(STK_CVR,0x00000000);
    PUT32(STK_CSR,5);

    uart_init();
    hexstring(0x12345678);
    hexstring(GET32(0xE000E018));
    hexstring(GET32(0xE000E018));
    return(0);
}
```

build

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m3 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m3 test.s -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m0 -march=armv6-m -c notmain.c -o notmain.thumb.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o notmain.thumb.elf -T flash.ld flash.o test.o notmain.thumb.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.thumb.elf > notmain.thumb.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.thumb.elf notmain.thumb.bin -O binary
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -march=armv7-m -c notmain.c -o notmain.thumb2.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o notmain.thumb2.elf -T flash.ld flash.o test.o notmain.thumb2.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.thumb2.elf > notmain.thumb2.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.thumb2.elf notmain.thumb2.bin -O binary
```

uart output as shown

```
12345678 
00FFE445 
00FFC698
```

If I take your code, make it shorter, don't have all day.

```
void soft_delay(void) {
    for (volatile unsigned int i=0; i<0x2000; ++i) { }
}

arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -O0 -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m0 hello.c -o hello.o
```

yes I know this is an m3

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GCC) 5.4.0
```

gives

```
00000000 <soft_delay>:
   0:   b580        push    {r7, lr}
   2:   b082        sub sp, #8
   4:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
   6:   2300        movs    r3, #0
   8:   607b        str r3, [r7, #4]
   a:   e002        b.n 12 <soft_delay+0x12>
   c:   687b        ldr r3, [r7, #4]
   e:   3301        adds    r3, #1
  10:   607b        str r3, [r7, #4]
  12:   687b        ldr r3, [r7, #4]
  14:   4a03        ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; (24 <soft_delay+0x24>)
  16:   4293        cmp r3, r2
  18:   d9f8        bls.n   c <soft_delay+0xc>
  1a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
  1c:   46bd        mov sp, r7
  1e:   b002        add sp, #8
  20:   bd80        pop {r7, pc}
  22:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
  24:   00001fff
```

first check the test infrastructure

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.align 8
.word 0,0


.thumb_func
.globl TEST
TEST:
    push {r4,r5,r6,lr}
    mov r4,r0
    mov r5,r1
    ldr r6,[r4]
inner:
    bl soft_delay
    sub r5,#1
    bne inner
    ldr r3,[r4]
    sub r0,r6,r3
    pop {r4,r5,r6,pc}

.align 8

soft_delay:
    bx lr
```

in the openocd telnet window

```
reset halt
flash write_image erase notmain.thumb.elf
reset
```

gives

```
12345678 
00001B59
```

7001 clocks, assuming the systick matches the cpu, thats 7001 arm clocks, 4 instructions per loop.

Step back note I aligned some things

```
08000108 <TEST>:
 8000108:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
 800010a:   1c04        adds    r4, r0, #0
 800010c:   1c0d        adds    r5, r1, #0
 800010e:   6826        ldr r6, [r4, #0]

08000110 <inner>:
 8000110:   f000 f876   bl  8000200 <soft_delay>
 8000114:   3d01        subs    r5, #1
 8000116:   d1fb        bne.n   8000110 <inner>
 8000118:   6823        ldr r3, [r4, #0]
 800011a:   1af0        subs    r0, r6, r3
 800011c:   bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}

08000200 <soft_delay>:
 8000200:   4770        bx  lr
```

both loops are nicely aligned.

Now if I do this:

```
0800010a <TEST>:
 800010a:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
 800010c:   1c04        adds    r4, r0, #0
 800010e:   1c0d        adds    r5, r1, #0
 8000110:   6826        ldr r6, [r4, #0]

08000112 <inner>:
 8000112:   f000 f875   bl  8000200 <soft_delay>
 8000116:   3d01        subs    r5, #1
 8000118:   d1fb        bne.n   8000112 <inner>
 800011a:   6823        ldr r3, [r4, #0]
 800011c:   1af0        subs    r0, r6, r3
 800011e:   bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
```

Simply changing the alignment of the code that is supposed to be testing the code under test I now get:

```
00001F40
```

8000 ticks to do that loop 1000 times with that call with the code function under test still being aligned

```
08000200 <soft_delay>:
 8000200:   4770        bx  lr
```

The .align 8, in general don't use .align with a number on gnu its behavior does not translate across targets.  .balign is better. Anyway I used it. The two words are because the align made TEST aligned, but inner is what I wanted aligned so I added two words to make it aligned.

```
.align 8
.word 0,0

nop

.thumb_func
.globl TEST
TEST:
    push {r4,r5,r6,lr}
    mov r4,r0
    mov r5,r1
    ldr r6,[r4]
inner:
    bl soft_delay
    sub r5,#1
    bne inner
    ldr r3,[r4]
    sub r0,r6,r3
    pop {r4,r5,r6,pc}
```

A little code review to make sure I didn't make a mistake here.

r0 is the systick current value register
r1 is the number of loops I want to run the code under test

The calling convention allows for r0-r3 to be clobbered so I need to move r0 and r1 to non-volatile registers (per the calling convention).

I want to sample the time the instruction before the loop and the instruction after.

so I need two registers for r0 and r1 and a register to store the begin time so r4,r5,r6 and that fits in nicely to have an even number of registers pushed on the stack.  Have to preserve lr so we can return.

we can now safely call soft_delay in the loop, subtract the count, branch if not equal to inner, once the count is done read the timer in r3.  from output above this is a down counter so subtract end from beginning, technically since this is a 24 bit counter I should and with 0x00FFFFFF to correctly do that subtraction, but because this isn't going to roll over I can assume out that operation.  result/return value goes in r0, pop everything which includes popping the pc to do the return to the C calling function which prints out r0's value.

I think the test code is good.

reading the CPUID register

```
411FC231
```

So that means r1p1, while the TRM I am using is written for r2p1 you have to be very careful to use the right document but also sometimes use the current document or all the ones in between if available to see what changed.

> ICode memory interface
>
> Instruction fetches from Code memory space 0x00000000 to 0x1FFFFFFF
> are performed over the 32-bit AHB-Lite bus. The Debugger cannot access
> this interface. All fetches are word-wide. The number of instructions
> fetched per word depends on the code running and the alignment of the
> code in memory.

Sometimes in ARM TRMs you see the fetch info up top near the processor features, this tells me what I wanted to know.

```
08000112 <inner>:
 8000112:   f000 f875   bl  8000200 <soft_delay>
 8000116:   3d01        subs    r5, #1
 8000118:   d1fb        bne.n   8000112 <inner>
```

this requires a fetch at 110, 114 and 118.

```
08000110 <inner>:
 8000110:   f000 f876   bl  8000200 <soft_delay>
 8000114:   3d01        subs    r5, #1
 8000116:   d1fb        bne.n   8000110 <inner>
```

This a fetch at 110 and 114, but not one at 118, so that extra fetch could be our added clock.  the m3 was the first publicly available one and it has a lot of features in the core that went away and similar ones came back. Some of the smaller cores fetch differently and you don't see this alignment issue.  with bigger cores like full sized ones they fetch sometimes 4 or 8 instructions at a time and you have to change your alignment even more to hit the boundary but you can hit the boundary and since it is 2 or 4 clocks plus bus overhead for the extra fetch you can see those.

If I put two nops

```
nop
nop

.thumb_func
.globl TEST
TEST:
```

gives

```
08000114 <inner>:
 8000114:   f000 f874   bl  8000200 <soft_delay>
 8000118:   3d01        subs    r5, #1
 800011a:   d1fb        bne.n   8000114 <inner>
 800011c:   6823        ldr r3, [r4, #0]
 800011e:   1af0        subs    r0, r6, r3
 8000120:   bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
```

gives

```
00001B59
```

So that's good we are back to that number, could try a few more to confirm but it appears that alignment is sensitive to our outer test loop, which is bad, but we can manage that, don't change it it won't affect the test.  If I didn't care about alignment and had something like this:

```
void soft_delay(void) {
    for (volatile unsigned int i=0; i<0x2000; ++i) { }
}
int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    unsigned int beg;
    unsigned int end;

    PUT32(STK_CSR,4);
    PUT32(STK_RVR,0x00FFFFFF);
    PUT32(STK_CVR,0x00000000);
    PUT32(STK_CSR,5);

    uart_init();
    hexstring(0x12345678);
    beg=GET32(STK_CVR);
    for(ra=0;ra<1000;ra++)
    {
        soft_delay();
    }
    end=GET32(STK_CVR);
    hexstring((beg-end)&0x00FFFFFF);
    return(0);
}
```

Then as I played with optimization options and I also played with using different compilers any change in the program/binary in front of the test loop would/could move the test loop changing its performance, in my simple example it was a 14% performance difference, that's massive if you are doing performance tests.  letting the compiler take care of all this without us being in control the everything in front of the function under test could mess with the function under test, as written above the compiler might opt to inline the function rather than call it making an even more interesting situation as the test loop while probably not as clean as mine, certainly not if not optimized, but now the code under test is dynamic as options or alignments change.

I'm very happy you happened to be using this core/chip...

If I re-align inner and now mess with this

```
.align 8
nop
soft_delay:
    bx lr

08000202 <soft_delay>:
 8000202:   4770        bx  lr
```

it's a single instruction which is fetched at 0x200 from what we have read and seem to be able to tell. wouldn't expect this to change anything and it didn't

```
00001B59
```

but now that we know what we know, we can use our experience to mess with this trivial Not interesting at all example.

```
.align 8
nop
soft_delay:
    nop
    bx lr
```

gives

```
00001F41
```

as expected.  and we can have even more fun:

```
.align 8
.word 0,0
nop
.thumb_func
.globl TEST
TEST:
```

combined gives

```
08000112 <inner>:
 8000112:   f000 f876   bl  8000202 <soft_delay>
 8000116:   3d01        subs    r5, #1
 8000118:   d1fb        bne.n   8000112 <inner>

08000202 <soft_delay>:
 8000202:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
 8000204:   4770        bx  lr
```

no surprise if you know what you are doing:

```
00002328
```

9000 clocks, 29% performance difference.  we are literally talking about 5 (technically 6) instructions, same exact machine code and by simply changing alignment the performance can be 29% different, compiler and options have nothing to do with it, yet, have not even gotten there.

How can we expect to do any kind of performance evaluation of a program using the time the code a bunch of times in a loop method?  We cant unless we know what we are doing, have an understanding of the architecture, etc.

Now as it should be obvious and reading the documentation I am using the internal 8Mhz clock, everything is derived from that so the systick times are not going to sometimes vary as you might see with dram for example.  The LATENCY bits in the FLASH_ACR register should have defaulted to zero wait states for 0 < SYSCLK <- 24Mhz.  If I were to bump up the clock above 24Mhz, the processor is running faster but the flash is now slower relative to the processor.

Without messing with the clocks and simply adding a wait state by changing the FLASH_ACR register to 0x31.

```
000032C6
```

12998 up from 9000, I didn't expect it to double necessarily and it didn't.

Hmm for fun make a PUT16 using strh, and

```
.thumb_func
.globl HOP
HOP:
    bx r2
```

and

```
PUT16(0x2000010a,0xb570); // 800010a:  b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
PUT16(0x2000010c,0x1c04); // 800010c:  1c04        adds    r4, r0, #0
PUT16(0x2000010e,0x1c0d); // 800010e:  1c0d        adds    r5, r1, #0
PUT16(0x20000110,0x6826); // 8000110:  6826        ldr r6, [r4, #0]

PUT16(0x20000112,0xf000); // 8000112:  f000 f876   bl  8000202 <soft_delay>
PUT16(0x20000114,0xf876); // 8000112:  f000 f876   bl  8000202 <soft_delay>

PUT16(0x20000116,0x3d01); // 8000116:  3d01        subs    r5, #1
PUT16(0x20000118,0xd1fb); // 8000118:  d1fb        bne.n   8000112 <inner>
PUT16(0x2000011a,0x6823); // 800011a:  6823        ldr r3, [r4, #0]
PUT16(0x2000011c,0x1af0); // 800011c:  1af0        subs    r0, r6, r3
PUT16(0x2000011e,0xbd70); // 800011e:  bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}

PUT16(0x20000202,0x46c0); // 8000202:  46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
PUT16(0x20000204,0x4770); // 8000204:  4770        bx  lr

    hexstring(HOP(STK_CVR,1000,0x2000010B));
```

gives
0000464B

and that was not at all expected. but is 18,000 basically

Putting ram to bed after this

```
PUT16(0x20000108,0xb570); // 800010a:  b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
PUT16(0x2000010a,0x1c04); // 800010c:  1c04        adds    r4, r0, #0
PUT16(0x2000010c,0x1c0d); // 800010e:  1c0d        adds    r5, r1, #0
PUT16(0x2000010e,0x6826); // 8000110:  6826        ldr r6, [r4, #0]

PUT16(0x20000110,0xf000); // 8000112:  f000 f876   bl  8000202 <soft_delay>
PUT16(0x20000112,0xf876); // 8000112:  f000 f876   bl  8000202 <soft_delay>

PUT16(0x20000114,0x3d01); // 8000116:  3d01        subs    r5, #1
PUT16(0x20000116,0xd1fb); // 8000118:  d1fb        bne.n   8000112 <inner>
PUT16(0x20000118,0x6823); // 800011a:  6823        ldr r3, [r4, #0]
PUT16(0x2000011a,0x1af0); // 800011c:  1af0        subs    r0, r6, r3
PUT16(0x2000011c,0xbd70); // 800011e:  bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}

PUT16(0x20000200,0x46c0); // 8000202:  46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
PUT16(0x20000200,0x4770); // 8000204:  4770        bx  lr
hexstring(HOP(STK_CVR,1000,0x20000109));

00002EDE
```

12000. 

The machine code did not change because I moved both back by 2 so the relative address between them was the same.  Note that bl is two separate instructions not one 32 bit one.  You cant see this in the newer docs you need to go back to the original/early ARM ARM where it is explained.  And it is easy to do experiments where you split the two instructions and put other stuff in between and they work just fine, because they are two separate instructions.

At this point the reader should be able to make a 2 instruction test loop, time it and dramatically change the performance of the execution of those two instructions on this platform using the same exact machine code.

So let's try the volatile loop that you wrote.

```
.align 8

soft_delay:
    push {r7, lr}
    sub sp, #8
    add r7, sp, #0
    mov r3, #0
    str r3, [r7, #4]
    b L12
 Lc:
    ldr r3, [r7, #4]
    add r3, #1
    str r3, [r7, #4]
 L12:
    ldr r3, [r7, #4]
    ldr r2, L24
    cmp r3, r2
    bls Lc
    nop
    mov sp, r7
    add sp, #8
    pop {r7, pc}
    nop

 .align
 L24:   .word 0x1FFF
```

this is I believe the unoptimized -O0 version.  starting off with one test loop

```
hexstring(TEST(STK_CVR,1));
```

experience, the times we are seeing will overflow our 24 bit counter and the results will be very strange or lead to false conclusions.

```
0001801F
```

98,000, quick check for safety:

```
.align
 L24:   .word 0x1F
```

0000019F

not bad that is on par with 256 times faster.

so we have some wiggle room in our test loop but not much try 10

```
hexstring(TEST(STK_CVR,10));

000F012D
```

98334 ticks per loop.

changing the alignment

```
08000202 <soft_delay>:
 8000202:   b580        push    {r7, lr}
 8000204:   b082        sub sp, #8
```

gave the same result

```
000F012D
```

not unheard of, you can examine the differences if you want count through each instruction check fetch cycles, etc.

had I made the test:

```
soft_delay:
  nop
  nop
  bx lr
```

its two fetch cycles no matter what the alignment or if I had left it bx lr with no nops as we saw so by simply having an odd number of instructions in the test then alignment won't affect the results on fetches along, but note that from what we know now had some other code in the program moved the outer timing/test loop that may have changed performance and the results may show a difference between two tests that were purely the timing code and not the code under test (read Michael Abrash).

The cortex-m3 is based on the armv7-m architecture.  If I change the compiler from -mcpu=cortex-m0 (all cortex-m compatible so far) to -mcpu=cortex-m3 (not all cortex-m compatible will break on half of them) it produces a little bit less code.

```
.align 8

soft_delay:
    push {r7}
    sub  sp, #12
    add  r7, sp, #0
    movs r3, #0
    str  r3, [r7, #4]
    b L12
Lc:
    ldr r3, [r7, #4]
    add r3, #1
    str r3, [r7, #4]
L12:
    ldr r3, [r7, #4]
    /*14:   f5b3 5f00   cmp.w   r3, #8192   ; 0x2000*/
    //cmp.w r3, #8192
    .word 0x5f00f5b3
    bcc Lc
    nop
    add r7, #12
    mov sp, r7
    pop {r7}
    bx  lr
```

000C80FB    81945 ticks for the code under test.

I hate unified syntax, that was a massive mistake, so I fumble along in legacy mode.  thus the .word thing there in the middle.

As part of writing this I kinda messed up my system in order to demonstrate something. I was building a gcc 5.4.0 but overwrote my 9.2.0 so had to re-build both.

2.95 was the version I started using with arm and didn't support thumb gcc 3.x.x was the first to.  And either gcc 4.x.x or gcc 5.x.x produced "slower" code for some of my projects, at work we are currently moving from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 for our build systems which if you use the apt-got cross compiler for arm that moves you from 5.x.x to 7.x.x and it is making larger binaries for the same source code and where we are tight on memory it is pushing us beyond what's available so we have to either remove some code (easiest to make the printed messages shorter, cut text out) or stick to the older compiler by building our own or apt-getting the older one.  19.10 does no longer offers the 5.x.x version.

So both are now built.

```
  18:   d3f8        bcc.n   c <soft_delay+0xc>
  1a:   bf00        nop
  1c:   bf00        nop
  1e:   370c        adds    r7, #12
```

these nops after bcc are baffling to me...

```
  18:   d3f8        bcc.n   c <soft_delay+0xc>
  1a:   bf00        nop
  1c:   370c        adds    r7, #12
```

gcc 5.4.0 is putting one, gcc 9.2.0 is putting two nops, ARM doesn't have the branch shadow thing of MIPS (MIPS doesn't currently either).

```
000C80FB gcc 5.4.0
000C8105 gcc 9.2.0
```

I call the function 10 times, the nop is outside the code under tests loop so has a lesser effect.

Optimized all cortex-m variants (to date) using gcc 9.2.0

```
soft_delay:
    mov r3, #0
    mov r2, #128
    sub sp, #8
    str r3, [sp, #4]
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    lsl r2, r2, #6
    cmp r3, r2
    bcs L1c
L10:
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    add r3, #1
    str r3, [sp, #4]
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    cmp r3, r2
    bcc L10
L1c:
    add sp, #8
    bx  lr
```

(also understand that not all say gcc 9.2.0 builds produce the same code when you build the compiler you have options and those options can affect the output making different builds of 9.2.0 possibly producing different results)

```
000C80B5
```

gcc 9.2.0 built for cortex-m3:

```
soft_delay:
    mov r3, #0
    sub sp, #8
    str r3, [sp, #4]
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
/*8:  f5b3 5f00   cmp.w   r3, #8192   ; 0x2000*/
    .word 0x5F00F5B3
    bcs L1c
Le:
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    add r3, #1
    str r3, [sp, #4]
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
/*16: f5b3 5f00   cmp.w   r3, #8192   ; 0x2000*/
    .word 0x5F00F5B3
    bcc Le
L1c:
    add sp, #8
    bx  lr

000C80A1
```

That's in the noise. despite the code built has differences.  they simply didn't gain in comparing the 0x2000 in fewer instructions.  and note if you change that 0x2000 to some other number then that does not simply make the loop take that much longer it can change the generated code for architectures like this.

How I like to make these counted delay loops is to use a function outside the compile domain

```
extern void dummy ( unsigned int );
void soft_delay(void) {
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<0x2000; ++i) { dummy(i); }
}

soft_delay:
    push {r4, r5, r6, lr}
    mov r5, #128
    mov r4, #0
    lsl r5, r5, #6
L8:
    mov r0, r4
    add r4, #1
    bl dummy
    cmp r4, r5
    bne L8
    pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
```

the feature there is you don't need the overhead of what volatile does you do have a call and clearly there is overhead as well due to the call but not as much

```
000B40C9
```

or even better:

```
soft_delay:
    sub r0,#1
    bne soft_delay
    bx lr
```

I would have to change the code wrapped around the code under test to make that function work.

Another note specific to these targets but also something you deal with

```
unsigned int more_fun ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    return(more_fun(a,b)+a+(b<<2));
}



00000000 <fun>:
   0:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
   2:   000c        movs    r4, r1
   4:   0005        movs    r5, r0
   6:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <more_fun>
   a:   00a4        lsls    r4, r4, #2
   c:   1964        adds    r4, r4, r5
   e:   1820        adds    r0, r4, r0
  10:   bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
  12:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
```

a question repeated here at SO on a period basis.  why is it pushing r6 it isn't using r6.

The compiler operates using what I call and used to be called a calling convention, now they use terms ABI, EABI, whatever either case it is the same thing it is a set of rules the compiler follows for a particular target.  Arm added a rule to keep the stack aligned on a 64 bit address boundary instead of 32, this caused the extra item to keep the stack aligned, what register is used there can vary.  If you use an older gcc vs a newer this can/will affect the performance of your code all by itself.

Comment: Damn, I exceeded the length again.  overoptimization isnt a thing, missed optimization is.  command line options make a big difference, yes.  if you are using a wall clock for reference then how the clocks are setup will make that change, but if you used the same source on both compilers that should not have happened.

Comment: I didnt have the space and spent plenty of time on this already and hopefully didnt make typos or dumb mistakes which is possible not compiling before running and getting a bad result (also a real life issue when doing performance testing).

Comment: Nor did I get to demonstrate as planned clock related stuff, using the slower clock will demonstrate the better performance at times for mcus if you are measuring in system clocks to do something, if you read the clocking information for this part you see that the system clock can do 72Mhz but APB1 can only do 36.  so it should be easy to demonstrate at 36Mhz or less that polling of a peripheral status register takes some number of system clocks to do then above 36 it takes more system clocks to do the same thing agreeing that the system clock is faster.

Comment: the point there being the performance is not linear particularly on a part like this if you run it at 8mhz against the wall clock blinking an led, then you take the same test code but set the system up for 72Mhz it is not 9 times faster, the flash is slower and the peripherals are slower (relatively), if you dont touch either then sure you can make a benchmark go 9 times faster against the wall clock by using the PLL.  read michael abrash.

Comment: with all of this ammo and some starting tips shown above, you can since I dont have Kiel, attempt to compare them to see why the differed.  remembering that even versions of gcc will differ relative to each other and it is expected for big projects to all the compilers to differ relative to each other, sometimes tiny test loops will optimize out to the same code across gcc, clang, etc.  and fewer instructions doesnt mean faster

Comment: answer long but 100% off-topic. it does not answer the OPs question, and is actually wrong.

Comment: @P__J__ I love it when you are around.  You did catch the part where a tiny program shows how large the measured performance difference can be multiply that through a large program or even one tiny bit of a large program.  Every bit of this is relevant as to why the OPs code could run slower or faster by tens of a percent.  What to look for and how to find it and test it.  Clearly explains why examining assembly/machine code is not remotely enough to understand performance differences.

Answer (score 2):

> Keil over-optimization (unlikely, because the code is very simple)

You cant over-optimize you can under/miss so if anything gcc missed something that Kiel didn't.  Not the other way around

> arm-none-eabi-gcc under-optimization due to wrong compiler flags (I use CLion Embedded plugins` CMakeLists.txt)

will see below but this is highly likely esp debug vs release, I never build for debug (never use a debugger) you have to test everything twice, and if you don't test as you go it makes it much harder to debug so the release version if it has issues takes a lot more work to figure out the issues.

> A bug in the initialization so that chip has lower clock frequency with arm-none-eabi-gcc (to be investigated)

My guess is it isn't this, this would imply you made a really big mistake and didn't compile the same code on each tool so it wasn't a fair comparison.

Let's run it.

Using the systick timer, 24 bit (current value register address passed in r0)

```
.align 8

.thumb_func
.globl TEST
TEST:
    push {r4,r5,r6,lr}
    mov r4,r0
    ldr r5,[r4]

    bl soft_delay

    ldr r3,[r4]
    sub r0,r5,r3
    pop {r4,r5,r6,pc}
```

to avoid overflowing the 24 bit timer the loops count to limited to 200000 times not 2000000 times.  I assume the code you left out is 2000000 - 1.  If not this still shows the relevant differences.

-O0 code

```
.align 8

soft_delay:
    PUSH     {r3,lr}
    MOV      r0,#0
    STR      r0,[sp,#0]
    B        L6.14
L6.8:
    LDR      r0,[sp,#0]
    ADD      r0,r0,#1
    STR      r0,[sp,#0]
L6.14:
    LDR      r1,L6.24
    LDR      r0,[sp,#0]
    CMP      r0,r1
    BCC      L6.8
    POP      {r3,pc}

.align

L6.24: .word 100000 - 1

08000200 <soft_delay>:
 8000200:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
 8000202:   2000        movs    r0, #0
 8000204:   9000        str r0, [sp, #0]
 8000206:   e002        b.n 800020e <L6.14>

08000208 <L6.8>:
 8000208:   9800        ldr r0, [sp, #0]
 800020a:   3001        adds    r0, #1
 800020c:   9000        str r0, [sp, #0]

0800020e <L6.14>:
 800020e:   4902        ldr r1, [pc, #8]    ; (8000218 <L6.24>)
 8000210:   9800        ldr r0, [sp, #0]
 8000212:   4288        cmp r0, r1
 8000214:   d3f8        bcc.n   8000208 <L6.8>
 8000216:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}

08000218 <L6.24>:
 8000218:   0001869f

00124F8B systick timer ticks
```

-O1 code

```
soft_delay:
    PUSH     {r3,lr}
    MOV      r0,#0
    STR      r0,[sp,#0]
    LDR      r0,L6.24
    B        L6.16
L6.10:
    LDR      r1,[sp,#0]
    ADD      r1,r1,#1
    STR      r1,[sp,#0]
L6.16:
    LDR      r1,[sp,#0]
    CMP      r1,r0
    BCC      L6.10
    POP      {r3,pc}
.align
L6.24: .word 100000 - 1


08000200 <soft_delay>:
 8000200:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
 8000202:   2000        movs    r0, #0
 8000204:   9000        str r0, [sp, #0]
 8000206:   4804        ldr r0, [pc, #16]   ; (8000218 <L6.24>)
 8000208:   e002        b.n 8000210 <L6.16>

0800020a <L6.10>:
 800020a:   9900        ldr r1, [sp, #0]
 800020c:   3101        adds    r1, #1
 800020e:   9100        str r1, [sp, #0]

08000210 <L6.16>:
 8000210:   9900        ldr r1, [sp, #0]
 8000212:   4281        cmp r1, r0
 8000214:   d3f9        bcc.n   800020a <L6.10>
 8000216:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}

08000218 <L6.24>:
 8000218:   0001869f

000F424E systicks
```

-O2 code

```
soft_delay:
    SUB      sp,sp,#4
    MOVS     r0,#0
    STR      r0,[sp,#0]
    LDR      r0,L4.24
L4.8:
    LDR      r1,[sp,#0]
    ADDS     r1,r1,#1
    STR      r1,[sp,#0]
    CMP      r1,r0
    BCC      L4.8
    ADD      sp,sp,#4
    BX       lr
.align
L4.24: .word 100000 - 1

08000200 <soft_delay>:
 8000200:   b081        sub sp, #4
 8000202:   2000        movs    r0, #0
 8000204:   9000        str r0, [sp, #0]
 8000206:   4804        ldr r0, [pc, #16]   ; (8000218 <L4.24>)

08000208 <L4.8>:
 8000208:   9900        ldr r1, [sp, #0]
 800020a:   3101        adds    r1, #1
 800020c:   9100        str r1, [sp, #0]
 800020e:   4281        cmp r1, r0
 8000210:   d3fa        bcc.n   8000208 <L4.8>
 8000212:   b001        add sp, #4
 8000214:   4770        bx  lr
 8000216:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

08000218 <L4.24>:
 8000218:   0001869f
    
000AAE65 systicks
```

-O3

```
soft_delay:
        PUSH     {r3,lr}
        MOV      r0,#0
        STR      r0,[sp,#0]
        LDR      r0,L5.20
L5.8:
        LDR      r1,[sp,#0]
        ADD      r1,r1,#1
        STR      r1,[sp,#0]
        CMP      r1,r0
        BCC      L5.8
        POP      {r3,pc}
.align
L5.20: .word 100000 - 1


08000200 <soft_delay>:
 8000200:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
 8000202:   2000        movs    r0, #0
 8000204:   9000        str r0, [sp, #0]
 8000206:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (8000214 <L5.20>)

08000208 <L5.8>:
 8000208:   9900        ldr r1, [sp, #0]
 800020a:   3101        adds    r1, #1
 800020c:   9100        str r1, [sp, #0]
 800020e:   4281        cmp r1, r0
 8000210:   d3fa        bcc.n   8000208 <L5.8>
 8000212:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}

08000214 <L5.20>:
 8000214:   0001869f

000AAE6A systicks
```

Interestingly alignment doesn't affect any of these results.

Comparing your results relative to each other and the above in a spreadsheet

```
18.7    1.000   00124F8B    1200011 1.000
13.3    0.711   000F424E    1000014 0.833
 9.8    0.524   000AAE65     700005 0.583
 9.9    0.529   000AAE6A     700010 0.583
```

It shows that the various stages as I have measured also show improvements and that -O3 is slightly slower.

Analyze what happened.

```
void soft_delay(void) {
    for (volatile uint32_t i=0; i<2000000; ++i) { }
}
```

because this counts up AND is volatile the compiler cannot do the usual count down and save an instruction (subs then bne rather than add, cmp, bcc)

-O0 code

```
soft_delay:
    PUSH     {r3,lr}      allocate space for i
    MOV      r0,#0        i = 0
    STR      r0,[sp,#0]   i = 0
    B        L6.14
L6.8:
    LDR      r0,[sp,#0]   read i from memory
    ADD      r0,r0,#1     increment i
    STR      r0,[sp,#0]   save i to memory
L6.14:
    LDR      r1,L6.24     read max value 
    LDR      r0,[sp,#0]   read i from memory
    CMP      r0,r1        compare i and max value
    BCC      L6.8         branch if unsigned lower
    POP      {r3,pc}      return
```

I should have examined the code first L6.24 should have been 2000000 not 2000000 - 1.  You left this out of your question.

No optimization generally means just bang out the code in order as in the high level language.

r3 doesn't need to be preserved neither does LR but the variable is volatile so it needs space on the stack the compiler chose to do it this way for this optimization level pushing lr allows for it to pop pc at the end.

push is a pseudo instruction for stm (stmdb)  so 8 is subtracted from the stack pointer then the registers are saved in order so if the sp was at 0x1008 then it changes to 0x1000 and writes r3 to 0x1000 and lr to 0x1004 so for the rest of this function it uses sp+0 which is 0x1000 in this example.  The r3 and the push used in this way is to allocate a location for the variable i in the code.

-O1 version

```
soft_delay:
    PUSH     {r3,lr}     allocate space
    MOV      r0,#0       i = 0
    STR      r0,[sp,#0]  i = 0
    LDR      r0,L6.24    read max/test value
    B        L6.16
L6.10:
    LDR      r1,[sp,#0]  load i from memory
    ADD      r1,r1,#1    increment i
    STR      r1,[sp,#0]  save i to memory
L6.16:
    LDR      r1,[sp,#0]  read i from memory
    CMP      r1,r0       compare i with test value
    BCC      L6.10       branch if unsigned lower
    POP      {r3,pc}
```

The primary difference between -O0 and -O1 in this case is the -O0 version reads the max value every time through the loop.  The -O1 version reads it outside the loop one time.

-O0

```
08000208 <L6.8>:
 8000208:   9800        ldr r0, [sp, #0]
 800020a:   3001        adds    r0, #1
 800020c:   9000        str r0, [sp, #0]
 800020e:   4902        ldr r1, [pc, #8]    ; (8000218 <L6.24>)
 8000210:   9800        ldr r0, [sp, #0]
 8000212:   4288        cmp r0, r1
 8000214:   d3f8        bcc.n   8000208 <L6.8>
```

1200011 / 100000 = 12

The bulk of the time is in the above loop.  7 instructions three loads two stores.  That is 12 things so perhaps its one clock per.

-O1 code

```
0800020a <L6.10>:
 800020a:   9900        ldr r1, [sp, #0]
 800020c:   3101        adds    r1, #1
 800020e:   9100        str r1, [sp, #0]
08000210 <L6.16>:
 8000210:   9900        ldr r1, [sp, #0]
 8000212:   4281        cmp r1, r0
 8000214:   d3f9        bcc.n   800020a <L6.10>
```

1000014 / 100000 = 10

```
0800020a <L6.10>:
 800020a:   9900        ldr r1, [sp, #0]
 800020c:   3101        adds    r1, #1
 800020e:   9100        str r1, [sp, #0]
 8000210:   9900        ldr r1, [sp, #0]
 8000212:   4281        cmp r1, r0
 8000214:   d3f9        bcc.n   800020a <L6.10>
```

6 instructions, two loads one store.  8 things 10 clocks.  The difference here from -O0 is that the compare value is read before/outside the loop so that saves that instruction and that memory cycle.

-O2 code

```
08000208 <L4.8>:
 8000208:   9900        ldr r1, [sp, #0]
 800020a:   3101        adds    r1, #1
 800020c:   9100        str r1, [sp, #0]
 800020e:   4281        cmp r1, r0
 8000210:   d3fa        bcc.n   8000208 <L4.8>
```

700005 / 100000 = 7 ticks per loop

So by some folks definition, this isn't honoring the volatile, or is it?  The compare value is outside the loop and the way this is written it should be 2000000 + 1, yes?  It reads i from memory one time per loop rather than twice but does store it every time through the loop with the new value.  Basically it removed the second load and that saved some time waiting on that read to finish.

-O3 code

```
08000208 <L5.8>:
 8000208:   9900        ldr r1, [sp, #0]
 800020a:   3101        adds    r1, #1
 800020c:   9100        str r1, [sp, #0]
 800020e:   4281        cmp r1, r0
 8000210:   d3fa        bcc.n   8000208 <L5.8>
```

The inner loop is the same as -O2.

-O2 does this

```
08000200 <soft_delay>:
 8000200:   b081        sub sp, #4
 8000202:   2000        movs    r0, #0
 8000204:   9000        str r0, [sp, #0]
 8000206:   4804        ldr r0, [pc, #16]   ; (8000218 <L4.24>)
...
 8000212:   b001        add sp, #4
 8000214:   4770        bx  lr
```

-O3 does this

```
08000200 <soft_delay>:
 8000200:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
 8000202:   2000        movs    r0, #0
 8000204:   9000        str r0, [sp, #0]
 8000206:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (8000214 <L5.20>)

 8000212:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}
```

Now that is fewer instructions yes, but the push and pop take longer they have memory cycle overhead, the subtract and add of the stack pointer instructions are faster than those memory cycles even with the fewer instructions.  So the subtle difference in time is the push/pop outside the loop.

Now for GCC (9.2.0)

For starters I don't know if Kiel was targetted at thumb in general (all variants) the cortex-ms or the cortex-m3 specifically.

First -O0 code:

```
-O0

soft_delay:
    push    {r7, lr}
    sub sp, sp, #8
    add r7, sp, #0
    movs    r3, #0
    str r3, [r7, #4]
    b   .L2
.L3:
    ldr r3, [r7, #4]
    adds    r3, r3, #1
    str r3, [r7, #4]
.L2:
    ldr r3, [r7, #4]
    ldr r2, .L4
    cmp r3, r2
    bls .L3
    nop
    nop
    mov sp, r7
    add sp, sp, #8
    @ sp needed
    pop {r7}
    pop {r0}
    bx  r0
.L5:
    .align  2
.L4:
    .word   199999

08000200 <soft_delay>:
 8000200:   b580        push    {r7, lr}
 8000202:   b082        sub sp, #8
 8000204:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
 8000206:   2300        movs    r3, #0
 8000208:   607b        str r3, [r7, #4]
 800020a:   e002        b.n 8000212 <soft_delay+0x12>
 800020c:   687b        ldr r3, [r7, #4]
 800020e:   3301        adds    r3, #1
 8000210:   607b        str r3, [r7, #4]
 8000212:   687b        ldr r3, [r7, #4]
 8000214:   4a04        ldr r2, [pc, #16]   ; (8000228 <soft_delay+0x28>)
 8000216:   4293        cmp r3, r2
 8000218:   d9f8        bls.n   800020c <soft_delay+0xc>
 800021a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
 800021c:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
 800021e:   46bd        mov sp, r7
 8000220:   b002        add sp, #8
 8000222:   bc80        pop {r7}
 8000224:   bc01        pop {r0}
 8000226:   4700        bx  r0
 8000228:   00030d3f    andeq   r0, r3, pc, lsr sp

00124F9F
```

Immediately we see two things, first the stack frame which Kiel was not building and second these mystery nops after the compare, gotta be some chip errata or something, need to look that up.  From my other answer that may be deleted by now gcc 5.4.0 put one nop, tcc 9.2.0 put two.  so this loop has

1200031 / 100000 = 12 ticks per loop

```
 800020c:   687b        ldr r3, [r7, #4]
 800020e:   3301        adds    r3, #1
 8000210:   607b        str r3, [r7, #4]
 8000212:   687b        ldr r3, [r7, #4]
 8000214:   4a04        ldr r2, [pc, #16]   ; (8000228 <soft_delay+0x28>)
 8000216:   4293        cmp r3, r2
 8000218:   d9f8        bls.n   800020c <soft_delay+0xc>
```

The main loop where this code spends its time is also 12 ticks like Kiel its the same just different registers which don't matter.  The subtle overall time difference is that the stack frame and the extra nops make the gcc version slightly longer.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O0 -fomit-frame-pointer -c -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m0 hello.c -o hello.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D hello.o > hello.list
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O0 -fomit-frame-pointer -S -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m0 hello.c
```

If I build without a frame pointer then gcc -O0 becomes

```
soft_delay:
    sub sp, sp, #8
    movs    r3, #0
    str r3, [sp, #4]
    b   .L2
.L3:
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    adds    r3, r3, #1
    str r3, [sp, #4]
.L2:
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    ldr r2, .L4
    cmp r3, r2
    bls .L3
    nop
    nop
    add sp, sp, #8
    bx  lr
.L5:
    .align  2
.L4:
    .word   99999

08000200 <soft_delay>:
 8000200:   b082        sub sp, #8
 8000202:   2300        movs    r3, #0
 8000204:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
 8000206:   e002        b.n 800020e <soft_delay+0xe>
 8000208:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
 800020a:   3301        adds    r3, #1
 800020c:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
 800020e:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
 8000210:   4a03        ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; (8000220 <soft_delay+0x20>)
 8000212:   4293        cmp r3, r2
 8000214:   d9f8        bls.n   8000208 <soft_delay+0x8>
 8000216:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
 8000218:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
 800021a:   b002        add sp, #8
 800021c:   4770        bx  lr
 800021e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
 8000220:   0001869f
 
 00124F94
```

and saves 11 clocks over the other gcc version unlike Kiel gcc is not doing the push pop thing so saving some clocks over Kiel but the nops don't help.

Update: I had the wrong number of loops for Kiel because it used unsigned lower instead of unsigned lower or same as with gcc.  Even the playing field, remove the nops fix the loops gcc is 00124F92 and Kiel 00124F97 5 clocks slower due to the push/pop vs sp math.  gcc 5.4.0 also does the sp math thing, with the nop 00124F93.  Being outside the loop stuff these differences while measurable are also in the noise when comparing these two (three) compilers.

gcc -O1

```
soft_delay:
    sub sp, sp, #8
    mov r3, #0
    str r3, [sp, #4]
    ldr r2, [sp, #4]
    ldr r3, .L5
    cmp r2, r3
    bhi .L1
    mov r2, r3
.L3:
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    add r3, r3, #1
    str r3, [sp, #4]
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    cmp r3, r2
    bls .L3
.L1:
    add sp, sp, #8
    bx  lr
.L6:
    .align  2
.L5:
    .word   99999

08000200 <soft_delay>:
 8000200:   b082        sub sp, #8
 8000202:   2300        movs    r3, #0
 8000204:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
 8000206:   9a01        ldr r2, [sp, #4]
 8000208:   4b05        ldr r3, [pc, #20]   ; (8000220 <soft_delay+0x20>)
 800020a:   429a        cmp r2, r3
 800020c:   d806        bhi.n   800021c <soft_delay+0x1c>
 800020e:   1c1a        adds    r2, r3, #0
 8000210:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
 8000212:   3301        adds    r3, #1
 8000214:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
 8000216:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
 8000218:   4293        cmp r3, r2
 800021a:   d9f9        bls.n   8000210 <soft_delay+0x10>
 800021c:   b002        add sp, #8
 800021e:   4770        bx  lr
 8000220:   0001869f    muleq   r1, pc, r6  ; <UNPREDICTABLE>

000F4251
```

10 ticks per loop

```
 8000210:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
 8000212:   3301        adds    r3, #1
 8000214:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
 8000216:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
 8000218:   4293        cmp r3, r2
 800021a:   d9f9        bls.n   8000210 <soft_delay+0x10>
```

Same as Kiel the load of the compare value is outside the loop now saving a little per loop. It was architected a little different.  And I believe the nops after the bls are something else. I just saw someone asking about why gcc did something that another didn't what seemed to be an extra instruction.  I would use the term missed optimization vs bug, but either way this one doesn't have the nops...

gcc -O2 code

```
soft_delay:
    mov r3, #0
    sub sp, sp, #8
    str r3, [sp, #4]
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    ldr r2, .L7
    cmp r3, r2
    bhi .L1
.L3:
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    add r3, r3, #1
    str r3, [sp, #4]
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    cmp r3, r2
    bls .L3
.L1:
    add sp, sp, #8
    bx  lr
.L8:
    .align  2
.L7:
    .word   99999

08000200 <soft_delay>:
 8000200:   2300        movs    r3, #0
 8000202:   b082        sub sp, #8
 8000204:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
 8000206:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
 8000208:   4a05        ldr r2, [pc, #20]   ; (8000220 <soft_delay+0x20>)
 800020a:   4293        cmp r3, r2
 800020c:   d805        bhi.n   800021a <soft_delay+0x1a>
 800020e:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
 8000210:   3301        adds    r3, #1
 8000212:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
 8000214:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
 8000216:   4293        cmp r3, r2
 8000218:   d9f9        bls.n   800020e <soft_delay+0xe>
 800021a:   b002        add sp, #8
 800021c:   4770        bx  lr
 800021e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
 8000220:   0001869f

000F4251
```

No difference from -O1

```
 800020e:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
 8000210:   3301        adds    r3, #1
 8000212:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
 8000214:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
 8000216:   4293        cmp r3, r2
 8000218:   d9f9        bls.n   800020e <soft_delay+0xe>
```

gcc is not willing to take that second load out of the loop.

at the -O2 level Kiel is 70005 ticks and gcc 1000017.  42 percent more/slower.

gcc -O3 produced the same code as -O2.

So the key difference here is perhaps an interpretation of what volatile does, and there are some folks at SO that get upset about its use anyway, but let's just assume that it means everything you do with the variable needs to go to/from memory.

From what I normally see that means this

```
.L3:
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    add r3, r3, #1
    str r3, [sp, #4]
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    cmp r3, r2
    bls .L3
```

not this

```
.L3:
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    add r3, r3, #1
    str r3, [sp, #4]
    cmp r3, r2
    bls .L3
```

Is that a Kiel bug?  Do you want to use your over-optimization term here?

There are two operations an increment

```
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    add r3, r3, #1
    str r3, [sp, #4]
```

and a compare

```
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    cmp r3, r2
    bls .L3
```

arguably each should access the variable from memory not from a register. (in a pure debug version sense you should see code like this too btw, although the tool defines what it means by debug version)

When you figure out which gcc you have and how it was used it may account for even more code on the gcc side being the 100% slower not 40%.

I don't know that you could make this any tighter, I don't think re-arranging instructions will improve performance either.

Also, this was a missed optimization in gcc:

```
cmp r3, r2
bhi .L1
```

gcc knew that it was starting from zero and knew it was going to a bigger number so r3 would never be larger than r2 here.

We wish for the tool to make this:

```
soft_delay:
    mov r3, #0
    ldr r2, .L7
.L3:
    add r3, r3, #1
    cmp r3, r2
    bls .L3
.L1:
    bx  lr
.L8:
    .align  2
.L7:
    .word   99999
    
00061A88

at 4 instructions per loop on average
```

but without the volatile it is dead code so the optimizer would simply remove it rather than make this code.  A down count loop would be slightly smaller

```
soft_delay:
    ldr r2, .L7
.L3:
    sub r2, r2, #1
    bne .L3
.L1:
    bx  lr
.L8:
    .align  2
.L7:
    .word   100000

000493E7
```

3 ticks per loop, removing the extra instruction helped.

> Keil over-optimization (unlikely, because the code is very simple)

You might actually be right here, not because it is simple, but what does volatile really mean, and is it subject to interpretation by the compilers (I would have to find a spec).  Is this a Kiel bug, did it over optimize?

There still isn't such a thing as over-optimization, there is a name for that, a compiler bug.  So did Kiel interpret this wrong or Kiel and gcc disagree on the interpretation of volatile.

> arm-none-eabi-gcc under-optimization due to wrong compiler flags (I use CLion Embedded plugins` CMakeLists.txt)

This could be it as well, for the same reason.  Is this simply an "implementation defined" difference between compilers and both are right based on their definition?

Now gcc did miss an optimization here (or two), but it accounts for a small amount as it is outside the loop.

Comment: Third answer based on your edit to the question, choose one and Ill delete the other two.

Comment: Once more I thank you for the brilliant and comprehensive answers. Please, do not delete any of them, IMHO it's a true detective story and must be preserved as is:). Later I will write a short summary so that anyone who needs a quick explanation will get it, and those who want to go into details can do it with the help of your posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
                 GCC              |||                  KEIL
                                  |||
soft_delay:                       |||
        mov     r3, #0            |||
        sub     sp, sp, #8        |||
        str     r3, [sp, #4]      |||
        ldr     r3, [sp, #4]      |||
        ldr     r2, .L7           |||
        cmp     r3, r2            |||
        bhi     .L1               |||        soft_delay PROC
.L3:                              |||                PUSH     {r3,lr}
        ldr     r3, [sp, #4]      |||                MOVS     r0,#0     
        add     r3, r3, #1        |||                STR      r0,[sp,#0]
        str     r3, [sp, #4]      |||                LDR      r0,|L5.20|
        ldr     r3, [sp, #4]      |||        |L5.8|
        cmp     r3, r2            |||                LDR      r1,[sp,#0]
        bls     .L3               |||                ADDS     r1,r1,#1
.L1:                              |||                STR      r1,[sp,#0]
        add     sp, sp, #8        |||                CMP      r1,r0
        bx      lr                |||                BCC      |L5.8|
.L7:                              |||                POP      {r3,pc}
        .word   1999999           |||                ENDP
```

There is obvious bug in KEIL. `volatile` means that its value has to be loaded before every use and saved when changed. ? Keil is missing one load.

The variable is used 2 times: 1: when increased, 2: when compared. Two loads needed.

Comment: old_timer has pointed this out in his answer with detailed analysis: "So the key difference here is perhaps an interpretation of what volatile does"

Comment: @Fedorov7890 it means the volatile is not volatile anymore. If something changes its value between the store and compare your function will not know anything about it. Another reason to **do not use Keil** (there are many others as well)

Comment: At least we've found what's going on here. BTW I'm not that categorical about Keil, it does well what it does. Sometimes violate law for the mutual benefit is not bad, if you know all consequences of course...